# Comparing the dates logic in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2005, linq-to-sql

I want to query the result

```
public resultType GetData(int ClientID, DateTime CreatedDate)
{
    var Row = DB.tblPlans
                .Where(m => m.fkClient_Id == ClientID && m.PlanDate <= CreatedDate)
                .OrderByDescending(m => m.Id)
                .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

But the results are not coming as required because the "m.PlanDate" in the query is comparing the time also. 
so The parameter "CreatedDate"  in the above function will always get  "12:00:00 AM" attached to it suppose  "2/17/2014 12:00:00 AM" 
because it is a datepicker control and I am converting it into datetime but the value of created date with which I have to compare it is having original timing suppose "2/17/2014 11:58:35 AM"

and that is why I am not getting the desired result.

I think the result will be fine if time portions get removed.

I have  searched the above problem and it have many solutions like::
using AddDays(1); but I am not sure about it's working.
also I tried::
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/499987/LINQ-query-to-compare-only-date-part-of-DateTime

Please suggest me a better way to do this as this is not the first time I am getting this problem.

Comment: The `AddDays` approach is the best approach, because when you convert a database value before comparing it Sql Server can't use indexes anymore. What is it you're nor sure of?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using Linq to SQL (as you specified in question tag), then simply get Date part of DateTime:

```
var Row = DB.tblPlans
            .Where(m => m.fkClient_Id == ClientID && m.PlanDate.Date <= CreatedDate)
            .OrderByDescending(m => m.Id)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

With Entity Framework you should use `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(m.PlanDate)`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
public resultType GetData(int ClientID, DateTime CreatedDate)
{
    var Row = DB.tblPlans
                .Where(m => m.fkClient_Id == ClientID && m.PlanDate.Date <= CreatedDate)
                .OrderByDescending(m => m.Id)
                .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to compare dates in linq queries if you are using EntityFramework 6 is `DbFunctions.TruncateTime(m.PlanDate)` and for previous versions `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(m.PlanDate)`