# Comparing nullable datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datetime, nullable

I am trying to compare dates in my linq query but my `c.DateRequired` is a nullable date field and I want to just compare the date without the time. How do I go about converting `c.DateRequired` in this case to just get the date.

```
   IEnumerable<SalesOrder> salesOrders = _uow.Repository<SalesOrder>().Query()
            .Filter(c => c.IsDeleted != true &&
                         (((c.DateRequired == DateTime.Today.Date)) && Period == 1) ||
                         (((c.DateRequired >= sDateP && c.DateRequired <= stDate)) &&
                          (Period == 2 || Period == 3)))
            .OrderBy(q => q.OrderBy(c => c.DateCreated))
            .Get()
            .Select(p => new
            {
                SalesOrder = p,
                SalesOrderDetailsList =
                    p.SalesOrderDetailsList.Where(pd => pd.IsDeleted != true),
                salesOrderDetailsComponentsList =
                    p.SalesOrderDetailsList.Select(c => c.SalesOrderDetailsComponentsList),
                SalesOrderDetailsComponentsInfoList =
                    p.SalesOrderDetailsList.Select(
                        i =>
                            i.SalesOrderDetailsComponentsList.Select(
                                info => info.SalesOrderDetailsComponentsInfoList))
            })
            .ToList()
            .Select(p => p.SalesOrder);

        return salesOrders;

    }
```

Comment: Similar question was asked recently [Comparing the dates logic in Linq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21823779/comparing-the-dates-logic-in-linq)

Comment: The answers you've got assume you're using Entity Framework. Your question doesn't specify, it's possible you are using that, it's possible you're not. Either way, please edit your question to clarify what you're using.

Comment: @hvd [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21824593/51) should work for Linq-to-Sql as well as EF

Answer (score 2):

Try to use something like this:

```
.Where(x => x.DateRequired.HasValue && 
            EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DateRequired.Value) == EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Today))
.ToList();
```

It works perfectly for me.

Comment: `x.DateRequired.Value` is causing exception, if `x.DateRequired` was null , `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DateRequired)` is right

Comment: am1r_5h, look at my answer onse more - there is part, which check this: x.DateRequired.HasValue.

Comment: did your condition have this `x.DateRequired.HasValue && ...` before ? anyhow its ok now, sorry

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime` which accept a nullable `datetime` to truncate time in linq

```
EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DateRequired) == EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Today)
```

Answer (score 1):

I answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21823779/comparing-the-dates-logic-in-linq/21825565#21825565).

The recommended way to compare dates in linq queries if you are using EntityFramework 6 is `DbFunctions.TruncateTime(m.PlanDate)` and for previous versions `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(m.PlanDate)`